# How to make keyboard input become an array, separated by characters?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I want to make it so that I make an array, and whatever the user inputs, each individual letter and number gets put into the array.  For example:

keyboard input: Hakuna Matata

and you would get an array that looks like this:

```
{'H','a','k','u','n','a',' ',' 'M','a','t','a','t','a', ...}
```

How would I go about coding this?

Comment: Are you trying to print a string as an array like that, or what?

Comment: Basically put the string into an array (but the string is keyboard input), so I can compare each individual character.

Comment: If you want it to be dynamic (ie. as a user enters more data it gets added to the array), it would be better for you to use a list rather than an array.

Comment: All I want to do is be able to look at part of the array, and compare some other variable to it.  Not change it at all once the user inputs a string.

Comment: In C a string is by definition an array of characters, no transformation needed. If you use `std::string` you can use `.c_str()` to retrieve the pointer to the array.

Comment: You'll need to intercept keyboard innput. What you can get might be more than appearing from `istream-get()` et al.

Answer (score 1):

That would be through a string:

```
std::string s;
std::cin >> s;

std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(),
          std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, " ");
```

Output:

> H a k u n a , M a t a t a